# Resistor with first band in color black

Tags: power-supply, resistors, 3d

I recently bought an Ender 3 3d Printer that comes with a cheap Chinese 24V 15A PSU. Unfortunately, the PSU went dead and by inspecting the board, I found out that two resistors were fried (both the same value). By looking at the resistor’s code bars, I see that the first band is colored black.

The bands read: BLACK, YELLOW, VIOLET, SILVER and BROWN. (Please see the picture below).

It appears that the last band is brown as it looks like is the one most separated from the others. I would appreciate if anyone can give me any hints on where or what resistors to get.

I already replaced the cheap PSU for a Mean Well. However just for the fun of it, I want to repair the dead one.

[image: RESISTOR]

Comment: it can be to have the "right" band number to have 5 bands even if only the yellow & violet are used to set the value ... I am not sure of that ...

Comment: Why don't you measure it?

Comment: If you have a question, what it is? Do you need help interpreting the resistor color code? The resistor does not look like it is burnt.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comments!!!! That is a picture I got on the Internet. Is the exact same resistor. Mine is burnt so when I try to measure it, I get OL. The question is to help determine the value of the resistor.

Comment: It would be easier if you googled instead of creating a StackExchange account just for asking this. But since you came here, be welcome. I hope that we can help you with problems more complicated than this. All that you need is in [this link](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-resistor-color-code-5-band).

Comment: Most of times, resistors are a symptom of the failure of another component. Most of times, PSU repairing is not an easy task of just replacing a simple resistor.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [resistor calculator](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-resistor-color-code-5-band) to get the value of the resistor:

[image]

This is a .47 ohm, 1% resistor. From the size of it, I'd say that this is a 1/2 watt (or possibly 1 watt) resistor, that will be the challenge to determine the wattage rating. You can order them from the site with the resistor calculator linked above, or just about any other site, just type it into Google.